# Manage http access to git repositories using gitosis

Tags: git, gitosis, githooks, gitweb, post-update

**[Update 9/16/2010]**

After looking into this last night, I realized that my original question was really asking 2 separate things:

1) Is it possible to set the post-update hook for all remote repositories created by gitosis (i.e. not have to manually perform `mv hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update` for after creating a repository in gitosis)  This is necessary for cloning via HTTP to work (dumb HTTP clients rely on the fact that `git update-server-info` is called from within the post-update hook).

2) Once the repository is accessible via HTTP, is it possible to turn access on and off using an option in gitosis.conf (something similar to `daemon = no` or `gitweb = yes`)

**--- Solution to question 1 ---**

It turns out that Git uses templates to create new repositories with the `git init` command.  By performing `mv hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update` within the template directory, all future calls to `git init` on my server will have the post-update hook configured correctly.  (On OSX the template directory is `/opt/local/share/git-core/templates/` for those that care)

The other requirement for this to work is turning on Apache rewrite rules so that the HTTP clone URL for the repository looks like `http//git.example.com/repo.git`

My rewrite rules in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` look like this:

```
# turning on mod rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# make the front page an internal rewrite to the gitweb script
RewriteRule ^/$ /cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi [L,PT]

# make access for "dumb clients" work
RewriteRule ^/(.*\.git/(?!/?(HEAD|info|objects|refs)).*)?$ /cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi%{REQUEST_URI} [L,PT]
```

**--- Still looking for a solution to question 2...HELP! :) ---**

Now that HTTP cloning works for all my repositories, I'm wondering if there is a way to manage HTTP access control using gitosis.  Setting `daemon = no` and `gitweb = no` turns off git-daemon and gitweb access for the repository, but since the Apache rewrite rules are still on, ***the repo is still clone-able*** at `http://git.example.com/repo.git`.  Any ideas on how to use gitosis to manage this?

**[The question I originally posted]**

Is it possible to manage http access to git repositories using gitosis?  For example, in gitosis.conf I can manage access for gitweb and git-demon using:

```
# Allow gitweb to show this repository.
gitweb = yes

# Allow git-daemon to publish this repository.
daemon = no
```

I'm currently able to clone my repository by issuing the following command:

```
$ git clone git://git.example.com/repo.git
```

However, when I issue the following command:

```
$ git clone http://git.example.com/repo.git
```

I get the following error message:

```
fatal: http://git.example.com/repo.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

However, if I log into my server and run the following from within repo.git:

```
# From http://progit.org/book/ch4-5.html
$ cd project.git
$ mv hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update
$ chmod a+x hooks/post-update
$ git update-server-info
```

then cloning via http works fine.

Is there any way to manage http access to the repository from within gitosis?

Comment: Not as an answer to your question but I have heard `gitolite` is the new, still maintained (and with more features) version of gitosis.

Answer (score 1):

Was gitweb already setup and working?  Check [this blog](http://hokietux.net/blog/?p=58) for instructions how to setup gitosis with gitweb.

BTW, Gitolite primary feature is that you can have very fine permissions.  ie. control permission per branch.

---

UPDATE: I think gitosis integration w/ gitweb is basically whether it shows up on the project list.  It doesn't control the permission to gitweb; that is done via web server (apache).

Comment: Yes, I have gitweb set up and working fine.  I updated my question after looking into this last night, should be more clear what I'm asking